# Enter China on a provincial airport like Dunhuang

Tags: china, customs-and-immigration, china-southern-airlines

I (European citizen, valid Chinese visa) am planning to fly to China from Almaty (Kazakhstan) to Dunhuang in China. Dunhuang is not offically an international airport. The journey would be in two steps, but with one booking / ticket:

1. Almaty to Ürümqi (international)
2. Ürümqi to Dunhuang

Where would the entry into the country happen? Do I enter the country in Ürümqi or in Dunhuang? Is it possible in Dunhuang?

Bonus question: Will my luggage be checked through?

Note: Both flights would be done with China Southern.

Comment: Since Dunhuang Airport is not international, you can't clear customs there anyways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CZ flies from T3 in URC, so you'll do everything in the same terminal. However, China inspects travellers coming to China right on arrival. When you get off your flight from Almaty, you'll be directed to immigration counters. Then you'll have to pick up your bag(s) and go through Customs. After that, you'll have to go up again and check-in for your domestic flight, in a separate section of T3.

Comment: A very rare instance when one edits the editor :)

Comment: Immigration happened in Ürümqi and we needed to claim the bagagge. Immigration took 1 hour just for the relativley small airplane coming from Almaty in the middle of the night. On the airport there are no folding knives with fixable blade allowed, even not in the luggage.

Answer (score 2):

You always do entrance formalities at your first point of entry to a country, in this case Urumqi. Not all passengers on the flight from Urumqi to Dunhuang will be coming from abroad, so it wouldn't make sense to do immigration controls in Dunhuang.

I don't know about the exact procedures in Urumqi but generally when you enter a country you collect your bag, go through customs with your bag, and then recheck your bag for your connecting flight. Signs at the airport should make it clear how to do this.

Comment: *"generally when you enter a country you collect your bag, go through customs with your bag, and then recheck your bag"* -- Do you have any evidence for your claim that this is **generally** like that, except that that's how it's handled in the US?

Comment: I've done plenty of international to domestic connections where passport control was done at the first point of landing, but the bags were transferred without needing my picking then up and checking them in again... Customs agents at the final destination were the ones doing the inspection (if they could be bothered).

Comment: @npl I can confirm that this is how it works in China.

Comment: @jpatokal I never doubted that.

Comment: As to the first paragraph, in some countries/airports you can directly transfer to the domestic flight at the first point of entry and complete all immigration/passport control and customs formalities at the final destination, with the bags checked through (might not be applicable here, but still)

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Do you have any concrete example of a country where immigration/passport control would only happen after a domestic leg?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not _will_ happen, but _can_ happen, depending on the flight. For example, Delhi in India has direct transfer from international to domestic for some flights, with immigration/passport control at the domestic destination

Comment: @GoodDeeds: How do they know which passengers to check when the domestic flight arrives? What's to prevent an international arrival from saying "I only came from Delhi, so I should not be checked"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm There is a separation between domestic and international airport areas, and such domestic flights operate through the international side. So all passengers have to "pass" through immigration, except that the boarding pass tells which passenger was on a domestic flight and which passenger was not (there is a big mark on the boarding pass). Domestic passengers just show their boarding pass and walk through, while others go through the formalities.